# XML-RPC error while running client

Tags: java, xml-rpc

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcRequest
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcRequestProcessor.decodeRequest(XmlRpcRequestProcessor.java:82)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcWorker.execute(XmlRpcWorker.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:139)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:125)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.WebServer$Connection.run(WebServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.WebServer$Runner.run(WebServer.java:642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the error I am getting when I run my client code on localhost in XML-RPC. I have made server and client in JAVA. my server process seems to be running ok. It is waiting for client requests successfully.

Following is my code for client.

```
package rpcpkg;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;

public class SimpleXmlrpc {

    public SimpleXmlrpc() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();

        try{

          config.setServerURL(new URL("http://localhost:8089/workspace3/JAVARPC/RPCSRC/rpcserverpkg/"));

            XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
            client.setConfig(config);

            Vector params = new Vector();
            params.addElement(new Integer(17));
            params.addElement(new Integer(13));

            Object result = client.execute("sample.sum", params);

            int sum = ((Integer) result).intValue();
            System.out.println("The sum is: "+ sum);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to call the server with another XML RPC client than the Java one?

Comment: no I havent. I want client to be in JAVA.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't troubleshoot with another client, to help you find out what's going on / what end the problem is on...

Comment: I agree with matt b.  This will can help determine if there is an issue with the server.  Also, do you have access to server logs?  Is their an error on the server?  Is your client even hitting the server?

Answer (score 1):

AS matt and Stu said, you can check the response of your XML-RPC server with another client.

Here is an example in python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xmlrpclib
import sys

def main(argv):
    client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8089/workspace3/JAVARPC/RPCSRC/rpcserverpkg/")
    xmlresponse = client.sample.sum(17,13)
    print xmlresponse

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```